# Is there research on taxi call times?

Tags: transportation, research, traffic, public-transport

we are simulating future traffic in cities using small autonomous shuttles. To get more realistic we are looking for research on how long people are calling their taxi in advance.

Sadly my googling did not lead to any result so I am curious whether anyone out there has an idea where to look or even knows some papers.